Duplicate Hibernate validation ConstraintViolations on Lomboks @Data bean
I have a Lombok bean:
@Data
public class Foo {

    @NotBlank
    @Schema(description = "Organization label")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[-a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$", message = "Label must be alphanumeric with dashes.")
    private String label;

}

The same bean is used for OpenApi generation, using the swagger-gradle-plugin. This plugin only scans the annotations on the getters, so I had to instruct Lombok to copy the annotations from fields to getters in lombok.config:
lombok.copyableAnnotations += javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
lombok.copyableAnnotations += javax.validation.constraints.Pattern
lombok.copyableAnnotations += javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty
lombok.copyableAnnotations += javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

However, the Hibernate validator now reports 2 errors for the same violation, since the validation annotation is registered both on field and getter. The Hibernate Validator documentation explicitly warns about this case and suggest to use annotation on either fields or getters.
What I need is moving annotations on the getter and having the fields w/o any annotation.
